# Smarty: how to cache properly?

Tags: smarty, template-engine, smarty3

Say I have a page that contains dynamic content (e.g. search results). What is the proper caching technique?

- Put `nocache` tags around the entire page?
- Put `nocache` tags around the segment of mark up that actually contains the dynamic data?
- Put `nocache` tags around the dynamic data?
- Somehow tell Smarty not to cache the dynamic data?

The dynamic data is assigned as a Smarty variable (e.g. via `assign`). I think I need to try to maximize caching, but am struggling a bit at what needs to be cached, how to un-cache, when to cache, when to un-cache, etc.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is mostly static, then put `nocache` tag around the entire segment of code that displays the dynamic content.

Instead, if every page of your website contains a bit of dynamic output, I suggest you to disable Smarty caching during Smarty class initialization.

Comment: Shouldn't I be trying to maximize caching? Almost every page will contain some dynamic content.

Comment: If the main content of that pages is dynamic, disable all the cache. If there are only small pieces of dynamic data, but the site is mainly static, use `{nocache}`. Smarty templates are not parsed everytime disabling cache. Smarty templates are only parsed when TPL is modified. Then a PHP "compiled" page is generated. So, don't be afraid about Smarty template parsing overhead. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl